# ハイブリッドアプリでホームボタンの制御

Tags: javascript, monaca, cordova

今、monacaでハイブリッドアプリを開発しているんですが、
端末のホームボタンが押されたときホームに戻るのを止めたいんです。
アプリを終了せず、そのまま置きたいんです。
現在、document.addEventListener('pause', function(e){　、、
でホームボタンが押されたとき何らかのアクションをさせることはできたんですが、ホーム画面に戻るのは変わらない状況です。ホーム画面に移動させない方法を教えていただきたいです。

＊AndroidとIOS共に支援しています。

Answer (score 1):

憶測ですが、ホームボタンを押した時にホーム画面に戻れなくなってしまったら、端末が実行するアプリケーションが固定され、その他のアプリケーションに切り替えできなくなってしまい、アプリケーションがOSを乗っ取るような形にになってしまうので、そういったことは出来ないのではないでしょうか。

Comment: コメント、ありがとうございます。
アンドロイド（ネイティブ）の場合はホームボタンの時何らかのアクションを追加できるから、ハイブリッドアプリでもできるのではないかと思いましたが、やっばりダメなんでしょうかね、、

Comment: 少し調べてみたのですが、バックボタンのキープレスは検出できるようですが、ホームボタンのキープレスはそもそも検出する事自体できないようでした。なるほど。そこでKimさんは`pause`を利用してアプリがポーズ状態になったことを検出することで間接的にホームボタンが押されたことを検出し、そこからどうにかできないか悩んでいらっしゃったワケですね。恐らく`homebutton`のイベントがトリガされない仕様になっていることからも出来ない確率は高いのではないでしょうか？iOSは絶望的に無理な気がしますが、Androidの場合は可能かもしれません。その場合はネイティブエクステンションを探すか、独自に実装する必要がありそうですね。